# Python: exposing all other submodules from a specific submodule

Tags: python, module

I've got a weird case:

```
mymodule
|- submodule1
|- submodule2
|- mysubmodule
```

I'd like to have two ways of importing `submodule1` and `submodule2`.

1. `from mymodule import submodule1`
2. `from mymodule.mysubmodule import submodule1`.

Meaning, I'd like one way to go through `__init__.py` of `mysubmodule`, and another one that doesn't pass through that. So `__init__.py` of `mysubmodule` must somehow reflect all submodules available to `mymodule`.

How would I go about that?

Comment: Is this just an experiment? Or do you have some overall goal that requires this kind of bizarre import structure?

Comment: My goal is to create an alternative namespace which will run some stuff before proceeding to the actual submodules code. Activating virtual environment, for example.